# Searching through C++ STL man pages without having to add "std::" every time

Tags: bash, man

I have installed `libstdc++6-4.7-doc` on a machine with Ubuntu, so I could look up for things like `std::pair` from the command line.

Is there a way to search for the same `std::` entries without specifying it? E.g. by typing `man pair` I would like to open the same man pages as typing `man std::pair` would open but only when there would no other man pages for these keyword.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can create a function to achieve this, eg.

```
function kman(){ str="std::$1"; man $str }
```

Now, instead of using man, use kman for your `std::` terms:

```
~$ kman pair
 No manual entry for std::pair
```

A workaround but serves the purpose of saving typing `std::` every time.

Comment: Of course that's one way to do it but I really need it to execute `man pair` (though it can be overridden `man` command).

Comment: @REACHUS An alternative is to go to the manpages directory and create symlinks to the respective files and removing the `std::` in the link name. Another alternative is to amend the man source code and add your own switch to take care of the `std::` prefix. I suppose the first one would be easier.

Comment: If you're OK with overriding the man command: This will show the man page for std::$1, and if that fails, it will run man normally: `function man() { command man std::"$1" 2>/dev/null || command man "$@"; }`